# App doesn't color status badges red

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

The iOS app doesn't give status tags, like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) their red color in the question header:

> [image]

Can this be added please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [image: A screenshot showing this question with both the required tag and a moderator-only tag colored as they are on the web.]

This will be in the next build, along with:

> [image: A screenshot of Portuguese Stack Overflow Meta's tag list showing correctly colored tags.]

Comment: It's bit more pinkish, but you're excused. ;)